# my jquery modal box has decided not to be modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I do not have the jQuery CSS modal files added to my site but assumed that when modal is set as true it would still disable the rest of my page. This does not seem to be happening. Is there anything that my code is doing that would disable the ability for the form to be modal?

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
    $("#bar").dialog({
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function(){
                $.post('remote_foo.php', $('#bar').serialize(), function(data){
                    $('#tracediv').html(data);
                })
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "cancel": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }//end of buttons
    }).('open');//end of jquery dialog
})// end of click function
```

Comment: The `dialog` widget uses an overlay element to emulate modality. Without at least the `.ui-widget-overlay` style rules, it won't work as expected. Is something preventing you from including them?

Comment: was just going to add all my css when i finished the foundation and function of my site. I guess ill add this one for now

Comment: `my jquery modal box has decided not to be modal` Are you implying that your dialog has a mind of its own, and has consciously decided not be modal despite your wishes?

Comment: one day that shall be possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery UI Dialog doesn't "disable" the rest of your page. It works by placing a div on top of the page so if I try to click on anything I am actually clicking on that overlaying div, and not the elements beneath. This gives them the illusion of being disabled though they really are not.

Since you do not have the CSS included on your page the overlay div is more than likely not being formatted correctly and not blocking access to your underlying elements.

Comment: so in theory we cant ever have a modal dialog that acts like an alert box?

Comment: @Chad, in addition, jQuery UI *should not* disable the page elements when displaying a modal dialog, because disabled elements are not [submittable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-submit), therefore preventing the form to be submitted correctly from the dialog box's UI.

Comment: @MikeZ even an alert box doesn't "disable" elements beneath it, it just forces you to focus on it. Which is just what the Dialog does.

Comment: @Mike, you can call [window.showModalDialog()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.showModalDialog) to display content in a "truly" modal box, but that will enter a true modal loop, and the remaining of your code will only execute when that modal box is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You do actually need to include the CSS, because rather than "disabling the rest of the page" it simply adds a `div` to the DOM with a class of `ui-widget-overlay`, which sets `position: absolute`.

The positioning, combined with the `z-index` makes the rest of the page unable to be clicked.